# Fetching data from different types of documents in one query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So, what I need is not *exactly* a join, but something very similar. The main difference is that all the data I need is in the same collection. The other answers I've seen, related to joins in MongoDB are all between collections.

In my collection I have different types of documents.

For the sake of example, consider these two:

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "action" : "logEventGA",
    "timestamp" : 1490795738759,
    "terminal" : "3533322585",
    "device" : {
        "cordova" : "4.3.0",
        "model" : "iPhone8,1",
        "platform" : "iOS",
        "uuid" : "785ED0AB-996D-4E54-8E0F-404FE076BE4F",
        "version" : "10.2.1",
        "manufacturer" : "Apple",
        "isVirtual" : false,
        "serial" : "unknown"
    },
    "action_GA" : "login"
}
```

and

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "action" : "loginAttempt",
    "timestamp" : 1483125811453,
    "terminal" : "3533322585",
    "id": {
        "doc": 23324355,
        "valid": true
    }   
    "httpCode" : NumberInt("200")
}
```

The defining characteristic of each one is their `action`. Depending on the `action` an object will have different informations.

So, I need a query to grab information from both these kinds of documents (actions "loginAttempt" and "logEventGA"), with something to match (join?) them - in this case, we can use the `terminal` attribute.

I tried running a query on the first type of document, than a `forEach` to grab the remaining data for the other type of document (doesn't matter the order) but it is painfully slow. Also, there are other criteria for each action (e.g. when action=loginAttempt, httpCode must be 200). Is there a way to do this all in one go?

Below is my attempt at the "join" for which the performance is sluggish. It takes like two seconds per line to process, and it seems to get slower and slower as it goes. Can't use this.

```
db.Logging.find({
    "timestamp": { $gte: new Date('2017-04-01').getTime() },
    "action":"loginAttempt", 
    "httpCode": 200
}, {
    terminal: 1, 
    "id.doc": 1,
    _id: 0
}).forEach(function(obj) { 
    let eventGA = db.Logging.findOne({"terminal":obj.terminal, "action_GA":"login"},{ _id:0, "device.uuid":1});
    console.log(obj.terminal+';'+obj.id.doc+';'+eventGA.device.uuid);
});
```

The expected outcome would be something like this (or as in CSV form in my code above):

```
{
        "terminal": 3533322585, // from either doc
        "uuid": "785ED0AB-996D-4E54-8E0F-404FE076BE4F", // from "logEventGA"
        "doc": 23324355 // from "loginAttempt"
}
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome ? Do you always have actions in pair ? Something like `db.collection.aggregate({$match:{action:{$in:["logEventGA","loginAttempt" ]}}}, {$group:{_id:"$terminal", first:{"$first":"$$ROOT"}, second:{"$last":"$$ROOT"}}})` . The above query match `actions` and group by `terminal` and project both the documents.

Comment: I edited the question and added the expected outcome.
Also, I need a second criteria when action=loginAttempt, and also one for logEventGA. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can use `$cond` expression in 3.2 and below version and `$switch` for 3.4 version in `$project` stage.

Comment: Do you care to write an answer showing me how? I fail to see how `$cond` would help me.

Comment: I'll try to add an answer shortly. I'm little vague too and we can work from here.

Comment: I added my attempt at the solution to maybe clarify what I need. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142084/discussion-between-christian-dechery-and-veeram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query. This will only work for a pair of two.

The below query sorts the data on `action` so it can use the sort to project the document fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{$match:{$or:[{ "timestamp": { $gte: new Date('2016-04-01').getTime() },
    "action":"loginAttempt", 
    "httpCode": 200},{"action":"logEventGA"}]}},
{$sort:{action:1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$terminal", "first":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}, "second":{"$last":"$$ROOT"}}},
{$project:{terminal:"$_id", device:"$first.device.uuid", doc:"$second.id.doc"}}
)
```